# Using $http to load Angular JS json file not working with filters

Tags: javascript, angularjs

At present I can load a bunch of JSON using the following:

```
$scope.properties = [{
    title: "Tai's Bull Country Inn",
    property_type: ['pub','hotel','bandb','restaurant','selfcatering'],
    location: ['coastal','rural','urban'],
}];
```

But if I try this, it doesn't work:

```
$http.get('json.js').success(function (data) {
     $scope.properties = data;
     console.log($scope.properties);
});
```

The console.log displays the correct stuff, but the filter functions I'm using give a bunch of errors, probably because they are firing before the data is loaded. Either that, or something is wrong with the way my json file is laid out. Here is a plunkr:

http://plnkr.co/edit/U97RTGZmsmhUJ4nhohbF?p=preview

I'm a bit new to all this - so it may be me doing something very obviously wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I think it has to do with your json file. Try this and it works for me:

```
[{
"title": "Tai&#8217;r Bull Country Inn",
"property_type": ["pub","hotel","bandb","restaurant","selfcatering"],
"location": ["coastal","rural","urban"]
}]
```